# Preferred Pandas solution to collapsing rows of comma-delimited data of varying length into single column

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe `df` in the form:

```
| a,b,c,d |
|  e,f,g  |
|   h     |
```

But, using a comma delimiter, want to collapse the values into a single column dataframe like:

```
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |
| e |
| f |
| g |
| h |
```

What's the most pythonic / Pandas-preferred solution to solving this in Python?

Comment: `df.assign(col=df['col'].str.split(',')).explode('col')`

Answer (score 3):

You should use `.explode()`:

```
df['col_1'] = df['col_1'].str.split(',')
df = df.explode('col_1')
```

Answer (score 1):

if it's a data-frame with size=(3,4), the following line can solve it

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with involves iterating over the rows of the dataframe:

```
new_list = []

for indx, row in table.iterrows():
  new_list += row[0].split(',')

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_list)
```